# Using PHP within a SCORM course

Tags: moodle, scorm

I am creating an online course via SCORM for Moodle 1.9. I have decided that using SCORM is really the only way to design the course the way I want. It doesnt need to work in any other LMS, just one; so I am not worried about compatibility across the board.

What is the best way to use PHP files within a SCORM course?

I have tried linking directly to an outside PHP file, which does "work", but returning back to the SCORM files is kinda wierd. I have to add in this obscure path:

```
<a href="http://example.com/file.php/3/moddata/scorm/2/scormcontent/complete.html">complete course</a>
```

Although I have not done much testing, the above technically works. But, I would like to know what the best practices are when it comes to using anything other than HTML and javascript in SCORM. Please help!

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree 100% with pipwerks' answer above. However, if you were absolutely sure you want to do this kind of "hack" you are describing, I would suggest that you link your SCORM content with ajax requests to your php file, so that the experience is as transparent to the user as possible. Of course, you should also be able to upload and execute php files from inside the SCORM's folder (I'm not sure if moodle supports this).

Answer (score 3):

I understand your goal, but one of the key points of SCORM is portability (the "S" stands for "Shareable"). As such, server-side code is specifically prohibited in SCORM courses, because you never know which server-side code an LMS will support.

SCORM requires a pure client-side solution, with JavaScript handling course-to-LMS communication. There is no 'best way' to use PHP (or any other server-side language) in a SCORM course, and by using PHP, your course will not be SCORM-conformant.

If you want to use server-side code, perhaps you should consider AICC instead of SCORM.

Comment: From what I've read, AICC is a dying technology; most posts about AICC in general will point me to SCORM. I could use javascript for most of what I want, be we think we need to interact with an outside DB to handle what moodle cannot. As well as session variables/post values. Essentially we want to create a "game" course, so you might imagine the hurdles we are trying to jump over for this.

Comment: You can also try the Tin Can API, which is a successor to SCORM and AICC.  It lets you track anything, anywhere. It's not baked into Moodle yet, but there are ways to get it working. http://tincanapi.com/developers/tech-overview/

Comment: Also, while AICC is not as popular as SCORM, it's not quite dead yet. In fact, it was just revised to include new CMI 5 data elements. http://www.aicc.org/joomla/dev/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=158&Itemid=34

Comment: I would like to personally thank you for your help. I've got alot of pressure to build this course and information on this sort of thing seems limited. Tin Can sounds great, I am currently looking into using it with moodle 1.9 if possible.